# Linux Server's network daemons won't boot on load

Tags: ubuntu, networking, boot

This happened a while ago, but I installed some software and it messed up my entire app-get command so I had to do all this manual deleting and stuff. Everything is fixed except now when I restart the server it doesn't start the networking daemon it and won't allow me to connect. I put in a ticket with the vps company and they said there servers and unmanaged and can only restart the daemons manually by doing:

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
/etc/init.d/ssh start
```

They said they cannot do it for me, but they told me this:

> The problem is that the networking script is not being called and in turn the SSH daemon is not being loaded
>
> you need to make some configuration changes to ensure they are started each time.
>
> Worst case you would put these two commands in the /etc/rc.local file as a quick and dirty solution whilst you try to diagnose the cause of the failure.

I tried `update-rc.d ssh defaults` and still didn't work.

Anyone able to help out? I'm not the best network admin.

My distro is Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Try the same for each file in `/etc/init.d` that start with `net`.  You may want to try the command ` for x in net*; do update-rc.d -n $x enable ; done` to see what might happen. Then run `update-rc.d` for any files missing start links.  Many network init scripts don't have stop links.

Comment: Get a better VPS provider.  While your server is unmanaged, they should at least be able to give you consulting services to fix it up.  This is especially important to you, since you don't have the knowledge to manage the machine yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create a symlink to the script in /etc/init.d in each of the /etc/rc#.d directories. That's the messy way to do it. In rpm installs you can use chkconfig, not sure what the equivalent is with ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for you responce. I'm not very good with kind of stuff, but if do you think you would be able to help me out? I'm not even sure what a symlink is :/

Comment: I believe you'd run: "update-rc.d -f ssh defaults", and "update-rc.d -f networking defaults"